# fix clojure keywords highlighting in sublime text

Tags: clojure, sublimetext2

Is there anybody here who knows how i can fix clojure keywords highlighting in sublime text?

```
:keyword
```

I probably need to modify Clojure.tmLanguage in the Clojure package, but it is a bit intimidating

It should be easy because, it just need to match all words that begin with colon but i can't figure out how to do it myself...

function names containing arrows are not well highlight neither

```
(defn foo->bar ...)
```

Any help will be welcome

Answer (score 1):

I just released a new version of the [Neon Color Scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) that includes expanded syntax highlighting for Clojure, including `:foobar` symbols. You can install it via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net).

Comment: `(defn foo->bar ...)` as @szymanowski mentioned still doesn't work using your color scheme.

Comment: @ComtriS would you mind opening a new [issue](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/issues) so I can take a look at this, with an expanded code sample (I don't write much Clojure these days)? Please also include a screenshot of what the code looks like with Neon vs. other color schemes. Thanks!